# Seleccionar hijos JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente `form`

```
<form class="card-body" id="product-form" onsubmit="addProduct(); return false">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"
      id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" class="form-control" onfocus="true">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <!-- step para permitir decimales -->
    <input type="number" step="0.01"
      id="precio" placeholder="Precio" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number"
      id="year" min="0" value="Codigo" placeholder="Codigo" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-primary">
</form>
```

Lo que quiero hacer es seleccionar todo el `form #product-form` y a partir de esta selección seleccionar los campos `#nombre, #precio, #year`, ya que dentro del mismo documento tengo varios forms los cuales los inputs tienen el mismo ID,
es decir seleccionar `#product-form > #nombre` por ejemplo, en este caso el elemento sera único ya que solo hay  un elemento `#nombre` dentro del elemento `#product-form`

he intentado con

```
 document.querySelectorAll('#product-form > #nombre')
```

pero no puedo tomar el valor escrito dentro de este, me toma todo el elemento en un arreglo `NodeList[]...`

y con

```
document.querySelector('#product-form > #nombre')
```

me retorna `Null`.

Comment: quieres los valores de estos inputs o el elemento ?

Comment: en los input cambia los `id` por `name` y luego haces `$('#formID  input[name=nombre]')` , los forms deberían tener un id único también ( único por documento sino siempre encuentra el primero )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo primero, hay una forma mas sencilla y es gracias al objeto `FormData` que permite acceder a todos los datos de un formulario, te dejo el ejemplo con tu propio codigo y lo explico mas abajo.

```js
function addProduct(form) {
    console.log(form);

    let myFormData = new FormData(form);
    let data = [];
    for (var pair of myFormData.entries()) {
        let key = pair[0];
        let value = pair[1];
        data.push({
            [key]: value
        });
    }

    console.log(data);

}
```

```html
<form name="myform" class="card-body" id="product-form" onsubmit="addProduct(this);return false;">
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" class="form-control" onfocus="true">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <!-- step para permitir decimales -->
      <input type="number" step="0.01" id="precio" name="precio" placeholder="Precio" class="form-control">
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
      <input type="number" id="year" min="0" value="Codigo" name="codigo" placeholder="Codigo" class="form-control">
   </div>
   <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-primary">
</form>
```

**Explicación:**

He tenido que agregar el atributo `name` a tus `inputs` ya que no los tenia, si estos no están presentes en los `inputs` el objeto `FormData` saldrá nulo.

Con esto puedes enviar cualquier formulario para que tu funcion `addProduct` se encargue de procesar los datos de tu formulario sin importar cuantos campos tengas en el formulario.

Ventajas:

- Si agregas un nuevo `input` no tendrás que agregar un
  `document.querySelector('#nuevoInput')` por cada nuevo elemento
- Puedes procesar todo como un objeto `key':'value'
- Es re-utilizable
- No te dispararas en el pie

Answer (score 1):

Antes que nada, la definición de `id` en HTML es un **identificador único**, no deberías estar usando el mismo id en distintos elementos.

Ahora respecto a tu problema es tu entendimiento del selector css:

```
#product-form1 > #nombre
```

el selector anterior indica "posicionate en el elemento con id 'product-form1' y luego en el hijo con id 'nombre'" pero el input con ese id no es el hijo directo, es el hijo de un hijo del form, cambiando un poco el selector funciona con ambas opciones

```js
alert(`test querySelector ${document.querySelector('#product-form1 #nombre').value}`)
alert(`test querySelectorAll ${document.querySelectorAll('#product-form1  #nombre')[0].value}`);
```

```html
<form class="card-body" id="product-form1">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" class="form-control" onfocus="true" value="nombre1">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <!-- step para permitir decimales -->
    <input type="number" step="0.01" id="precio" name="precio" placeholder="Precio" class="form-control" value="precio1">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" id="year" name="year" min="0" value="Codigo" placeholder="Codigo" class="form-control" value="año1">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-primary">
</form>
<form class="card-body" id="product-form2">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" class="form-control" onfocus="true" value="nombre2">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <!-- step para permitir decimales -->
    <input type="number" step="0.01" id="precio" name="precio" placeholder="Precio" class="form-control" value="precio2">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" id="year" name="year" min="0" value="Codigo" placeholder="Codigo" class="form-control" value="año2">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-primary">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Una forma sencilla es añadir identificadores por medio del atributo `name` y estos estarán accesibles como propiedades del elemento `HTMLFormElement`:

```js
function addProduct() {
  const name = this.nombre.value;
  const price = parseInt(this.precio.value, 10);
  const year = parseInt(this.year.value, 10);
  alert(`Producto: ${name} - Precio: ${price} - Año: ${year}`);
}
```

```html
<form class="card-body" id="product-form" onsubmit="addProduct(); return false">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" class="form-control" onfocus="true">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <!-- step para permitir decimales -->
    <input type="number" step="0.01" id="precio" name="precio" placeholder="Precio" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="number" id="year" name="year" min="0" value="Codigo" placeholder="Codigo" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-block btn-outline-primary">
</form>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo voy a probar

Answer (score 0):

Intenta seleccionando los id's de los elementos que necesitas en un sólo selector, algo así como: `document.querySelector("#nombre, #precio, #year");`

O lo puedes hacer con jQuery más sencillo,

```
$('#product-form').each(function(){
     $(this).find($(#nombre, #precio, #year));
});
```